# JFileChooser not following look and feel

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

i am making a text editor, and this is the basic version of my code. I used     `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` to make the whole thing look like the platform I am using, but the JFileChooser `save` is always the java look and feel. Can anybody help? I might be putting it in the wrong spot, but I don't know where

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class TextEditor extends JPanel {
    static Container pane;
    static Container paneText;
    static BasicFrame frame;
    static JTextArea textArea;
    static JScrollPane areaScrollPane;
    static FileFilter txtFile;
    static JFileChooser save = new FileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home//documents"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,               UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, IOException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        frame = BasicFrame.getInstance();
        pane = frame.getContentPane();
        paneText = new JPanel();
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        int hGap = 10;
        int vGap = 20;
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, hGap, vGap));
        Action SaveAs = new SaveAs("Save File", "Writes the text file");
        JButton one = new JButton(SaveAs);
        one.addActionListener(null);
        txtFile = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File (.txt)", "txt");
        save.addChoosableFileFilter(txtFile);
        save.setFileFilter(txtFile);
        save.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
        pane.add(areaScrollPane);
        pane.add(one);
        pane.add(paneText);
        paneText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(paneText, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.setSize(450, 320);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class SaveAs extends AbstractAction {
        public SaveAs(String text, String desc) {
            super(text);
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            save.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
            save.setApproveButtonText("Save");
            save.setSelectedFile(new File("new 1"));
            int actionDialog = save.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (actionDialog != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return;
            } else {
                log("Done!", true);
            }
            String name = save.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            if (!name.endsWith(".txt") && save.getFileFilter() == txtFile) {
                name += ".txt";
            }
            BufferedWriter outFile = null;
            try {
                outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(name));
                textArea.write(outFile);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (outFile != null) {
                    try {
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioee) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void log(String msg, boolean remove) {

            JLabel label1;
            label1 = new JLabel(msg);
            if (remove) {
                paneText.removeAll();
            }
            paneText.add(label1);
            paneText.validate();
            pane.validate();
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    paneText.removeAll();
                    paneText.validate();
                    pane.validate();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JFileChooser` in your code is `static` and therefore is instantiated before the Look and Feel is set in `main`.

Set the Look and Feel before instantiation.  So, both in a `static` block since your `JFileChooser` is `static`.

```
...
static FileFilter txtFile;
static JFileChooser save;

static {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
           InstantiationException | 
           IllegalAccessException | 
           UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    save = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home//documents"));
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    frame = new JFrame();
    pane = frame.getContentPane();
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I moved the `save = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home//documents"));` out of the block and added it after, and got rid of the "static" on the block because it was giving me errors, but now i get a  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:` and 5 `save cannot be resolved` and then a `at guiWithSwing.TextEditor.main(TextEditor.java:84)`

Comment: I fixed the error so i could test the code, but it doesn't do anything. Now everything, including the buttons, have the java look and feel

Comment: You need to have the `static` block to set the L&F and initialize the File Chooser. Because your File Chooser is static, if you dont have the static block, the file chooser will be initialized before the L&F is set, without results. For your error: You need to have `static JFileChooser save` and also the `static` block. Looks like you removed the declaration also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.getProperty("user.home//documents")`, type `(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/documents")` (Assuming your documents folder is called "documents"). The former would return `null`, setting the `JFileChooser`'s location to its default -- the user's home directory.

This is because `"user.home//documents"` is not a defined key for `System.getProperty()`, while `"user.home"` is.

You should also set your `JFileChooser` to a `new JFileChooser(<path>)` rather than a `new FileChooser(<path>)`

Answer (score 0):

The LookAndFeel declaration must be made before the initialization of the Object, otherwise the object won't take on those LookAndFeel properties.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

THEN

```
save = new FileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home//documents"));
```